# When I add a Typescript Service to AngularJS will it be a singleton?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Given this example:

```
class AppController {
    static $inject = [
        'configService'
    ]
    constructor(
        public config: IConfigService          // Injected into parent
        ) {  
    }
} 
class AdminHomeController {
    public app: AppController;
    static $inject = [
        'configService'
    ];
    constructor(
        public config: IConfigService         // Injected into child
        ) {
    }
}
```

I inject into the parent and the child.  Can someone tell me if those ConfigServices will be the same or different instances of IConfigService **Typescript Class** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) says about services:

> Angular services are substitutable objects that are wired together using dependency injection (DI). You can use services to organize and share code across your app.
>
> Angular services are:
>
> - Lazily instantiated – Angular only instantiates a service when an application component depends on it.
> - **Singletons – Each component dependent on a service gets a reference to the single instance generated by the service factory.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: But is this still the same if I use Typescript classes?

Comment: @Alan yes its the same